# Jaspersoft Studio - User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am using Jaspersoft Studio 5.6.2 in OpenSUSE. When I start to create a new report, preview it, the following exception is thrown out, and I cannot open "Design" and "Preview" panel anymore. And the worse is, I cannot even create any new report at all.

**My report does not use org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger at all.**

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 16; Error at line 8 char 16: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:301)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.JrxmlEditor.doInitModel(JrxmlEditor.java:666)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.JrxmlEditor.init(JrxmlEditor.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createSite(EditorManager.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:647)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 16; Error at line 8 char 16: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:3363)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:3389)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1348)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigester.endElement(JRXmlDigester.java:199)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1892)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:297)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:874)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(MethodUtils.java:943)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.MethodUtils.invokeMethod(MethodUtils.java:275)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.CallMethodRule.end(CallMethodRule.java:632)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:257)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1345)
    ... 93 more
```